# Code stops its execution when access to database was denied, instead of handling the error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to perform a connection between PHP and a MySQL database via Mysqli. I have the following code:

```
<?php
$database_host = "localhost";
$database_username = "root";
$database_password = "";
$database_name = "test3";

$connection = new mysqli ($database_host, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name);

if ($connection->connect_errno) {
     echo ("Can't connect to database because $connection->connect_error"); }

else {
     echo ("Connection was successful"); }
?>
```

I'm using this code for a setup wizard for the users to install a software in their webservers. The point is that if the credentials are correct it prints "Connection was successful", but if wrong its output is:

```
**Fatal error**: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/uuid/index.php:55

Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/uuid/index.php(55): mysqli-&gt;__construct('localhost', 'root', '', 'test3')
#1 {main}
  thrown in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/uuid/index.php** on line **55**
```

I currently have error reporting for PHP on (without it, I couldn't get this error message), but regular users who upload the software to a web hosting and they input incorrect credentials will receive a blank page instead.

So how can I print "Can't connect to database because [...]", so users know why is this error being thrown?

Comment: Why should the users know that your code can't connect to the database? You should show them a generic error, not a specific error about database connection. That's something you should fix as a developer.

Comment: This code doesn't look like a setup wizard

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 8.1.0, MySQLi sets the report mode to `MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT` by default. This causes MySQLi errors to throw exceptions.

So catch the exception and report the error how you want:

```
try {
  $connection = new mysqli ($database_host, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name);
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
  echo "Can't connect to database because $e";
  ... return appropriate http status code ...
}

echo "Connection was successful";
```

Note: The above is just a quick example of handling an exception. Error handling and reporting is a more complex topic, and this is not meant to show the best practice for every application case.